# adding a plotline to one of two highstock panes

Tags: highcharts

the following plotLine object on the xAxis is adding lines to both panes 
how can i make this code add a line just to the first pane ? without affecting the rest of the panes 
and also same thing to the plotBands 
Thanks

here is the code

```
           xAxis: {

              plotLines: [{
              value: 1180656000000,
                  color: 'green',
                  dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                  width: 2,
                  label: {
                      text: 'prerinse'
                  }
              }, {
                  value: 1256227606000,
                  color: 'red',
                  dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                  width: 2,
                  label: {
                      text: 'postrinse'
                  }
              }]

              },




                  yAxis: [{
                      title: {
                          text: 'OHLC',
                      },

                      height: 200,
                      lineWidth: 2
                  }, {
                      title: {
                          text: 'Volume'
                      },
                      top: 300,
                      height: 100,
                      plotLines: [{value:500}],
                      offset: 0,
                      lineWidth: 2
                  }],

                      series: [{
                          type: 'candlestick',
                          name: 'AAPL',
                          data: ohlc,
                          dataGrouping: {
                              units: groupingUnits
                          }
                      }, {
                          type: 'column',
                          name: 'Volume',
                          data: volume,
                          yAxis: 1,
                          dataGrouping: {
                              units: groupingUnits
                          }
```

Comment: i need that plotLine on the xAxis to affect just one panenot both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
series: [{
type: 'candlestick',
name: 'AAPL',
data: ohlc,
dataGrouping: {
units: groupingUnits
}
}, 
{
type: 'column',
name: 'newline',
data: newdata,
yAxis: 1, <-This
dataGrouping: {
units: groupingUnits
},

{
type: 'column',
name: 'Volume',
data: volume,
yAxis: 1,
dataGrouping: {
units: groupingUnits
}
```

This adds second pane to y axis. If you change pointed line in code to "xAxis: 0", then new pane will be added to x axis.